# how to fast copy a large innodb table

Tags: mysql

how to fast copy mysql innodb table  size 8.4G?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the fast way is to copy the files but to do this in innodb engine 
you need to use

Per-Table [Tablespaces](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-multiple-tablespaces.html)

> Using multiple tablespaces can be
>   beneficial to users who want to move
>   specific tables to separate physical
>   disks or who wish to restore backups
>   of single tables quickly without
>   interrupting the use of other InnoDB
>   tables.