# Make a copy of large Innodb Database table in same database(MySql)

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to fast copy a large innodb table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3758334/how-to-fast-copy-a-large-innodb-table)

I want to make a copy of my Innodb table within the same Database. Table contains around 4Million records. I want the new copy of table for just testing purpose. In newly copied table i just want to alter structure slightly( Like i want to delete old Primary key and then make a new composite primary key and add logical partitions by RANGE) but content will remain the same.

I tried Phpmyadmin to copy that innodb table but it takes too long, then i decided to kill the process deliberately because it ate up server resources.

What would be the best way of making a copy of that table with some changes in structure(Removing old PK and add a new composite PK and add logical partitions by RANGE) as well??

Is there any way if i first just copy the structure and make required changes in it and then copy the data? Please keep in mind that the table is Innodb with around 4 Million records in it!!!

As far as i concluded that PHPMyadmin is not a good way for it.

Comment: i went through that post ^^^ but the answer was not useful for me. Probably i am a newbie

Answer (score 0):

You can create your new table structure and set the PK and indexes.

Then use a INSERT ... SELECT query to get the data from the other table into the new table.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-select.html

Comment: would that slowed down the whole process?? i mean first selecting and then inserting around 4 Million records?